# posting multiple images to a service with on screen feedback

Tags: android, android-asynctask, loopj

I'm fairly new to Android development and have a lot to catch on.
I have a conceptual question. What seems to be fairly straight forward to do in IOS, I can't figure out in Android.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I need to iterate over the device photos and post them one at a time to some web service.

- while image is uploading, I need to show the currently uploading photo on the screen together with a progress bar of current upload.
- I also need to show total count of photos left to be uploaded.
- Along with that I need to have 2 buttons on the screen -- "Cancel current upload" and "Pause all" (hope it's pretty self explanatory what these buttons need to do).

The problem is, that while iterating via MediaStore, it seems to lock the current thread and, if I do it on the main UI thread, then, obviously, the images would be uploading, but I would not see anything on the screen until all uploads are done. In order to overcome that, I'm trying to start a new AsyncTask and iterate that way. For uploads I'm using loopj library, which can only upload asynchronously when the upload started from the main UI thread. Since upload starts from the thread AsychTask is running on, I'm forced to use Synchronous client, which does not return back a response handle until the upload is finished, which means I would never be able to cancel currently uploading operation. To overcome that, I'm trying to spawn new intent for every image upload from AsynchTask iterator and wait for it to return until moving onto the next interator cycle, which has a horrible appearance -- Intents screens pop up and fold down with animation which is too annoying and looks horrible.
Aghhh -- the solution I'm describing is so complex. I'm sure, I'm overlooking something dumb simple. 
Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

P.S. The code can be found here: 
https://github.com/echowaves/Echowaves.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/echowaves/android/UploadProgressActivity.java
https://github.com/echowaves/Echowaves.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/echowaves/android/UploadProgressDetailsActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

I got a somewhat working solution. Instead of firing up a new intent for every upload, I just iterate over the MediaStore assets in AsynchTask and start asynch upload inside onProgressUpdate, and, since (if I understand it correctly) onProgressUpdate works on main UI thread, updating UI works like a charm. However, still, have to play tricks with setting flag indicating that the upload is currently active, sleeping for 100ms, checking for the flag, and once the upload is done, move on to the next image in cursor.

The latest code is updated on github:
https://github.com/echowaves/Echowaves.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/echowaves/android/UploadProgressActivity.java